# Folder operation in .bat is unstable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, mkdir, cd

I write a .bat to automate generating and compiling a cmake project. The batch file will

1. optional `rmdir build`
2. `mkdir build` if not exist
3. `cd build`
4. `cmake ..` generate a nmake project from upper folder
5. `nmake` compile project

the source:

```
@ECHO OFF
set "OpenCV_LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.1"
echo !! OpenCV Library: [ %OpenCV_LIB% ]
IF NOT EXIST "%OpenCV_LIB%" (
    echo Can't find OpenCV Library, please change OpenCV_LIB setting
    GOTO END
)

if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86   set BUILD_ARCH=x86
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 set BUILD_ARCH=x86_amd64
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==IA64  set BUILD_ARCH=x86_IPF
echo !! Target architecture [ %BUILD_ARCH% ]
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %BUILD_ARCH%

cd "sikuli-script"
set /p answer=Do you want to make clean first? (Y/N):
if %answer% == Y ( IF EXIST build rmdir /s /q build )
if %answer% == y ( IF EXIST build rmdir /s /q build )

IF NOT EXIST build mkdir build
cd build

IF NOT EXIST CMakeCache.txt ( cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D "OpenCV_DIR=%OpenCV_LIB%" .. )
nmake

:END
pause
```

After i run this .bat over and over, i notice that `cd build` failed sometimes, so i change my code to test it:

```
@ECHO ON
set /p answer=Do you want to make clean first? (Y/N):
if %answer% == Y ( IF EXIST build rmdir /s /q build )
if %answer% == y ( IF EXIST build rmdir /s /q build )
:DO_MKDIR_CD
IF NOT EXIST build mkdir build
cd build
if errorlevel 1 (
    pause
    GOTO DO_MKDIR_CD
)
```

It comes out the error happens every time choose to clean up `build`, even the `build` is at small size (e.g. after interrupted compiling, size 3.08 MB, 183 files, 67 dirs).

```
!! OpenCV Library: [ C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV2.1 ]
!! Target architecture [ x86_amd64 ]
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x64 cross tools.

D:\repo\sikuli>cd "sikuli-script"

D:\repo\sikuli\sikuli-script>set /p answer=Do you want to make clean first? (Y/N):
Do you want to make clean first? (Y/N):y

D:\repo\sikuli\sikuli-script>if y == Y (IF EXIST build rmdir /s /q build  )

D:\repo\sikuli\sikuli-script>if y == y (IF EXIST build rmdir /s /q build  )

D:\repo\sikuli\sikuli-script>IF NOT EXIST build mkdir build

D:\repo\sikuli\sikuli-script>cd build
Access is denied.

D:\repo\sikuli\sikuli-script>if errorlevel 1 (
pause
 GOTO DO_MKDIR_CD
)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So every time after remove and recreate `build`, the `cd build` fails, then `cmake` start messing up my source tree.

The error check and loop trying could fix this problem, but why is the file system not stable? or am i writing it in a wrong way?

Comment: just how deep did you run this loop? NTFS is forgiving,b ut you can't build paths of infinite depth. The path has a max of ~32k chars for unicode and 260chars for ansi

Comment: What are trying to do with the batch file, actually? Perhaps someone can give an alternative method.

Comment: I think it's not too deep, the batch file does "mkdir build" at D:\repo\sikuli\sikuli-script\

Comment: @HansPassant Tried to disable my virus scanner, it still happens. however thanks for letting the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That build directory check:

```
IF NOT EXIST build mkdir build
```

Will create the directory if both directory *and* file named "build" are not exist.

One way to check a directoy existence is:

```
if exist build\nul echo directory exist
```

If you want to make sure a directory exist use:

```
if not exist build\nul mkdir build
```

or better:

```
if not exist build\nul (
  mkdir build
  if not exist build\nul (
    echo mkdir failed
    goto :eof
  )
)
```